# Why do my color management settings not save after I log out of windows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile, color-management

I started to notice that whenever I saved an image in Photoshop, if I opened it back up in Windows Photo application, it would open with a yellowish filter.

I learned that this was due to the color management settings of the screen. I then started digging around in the color management settings of Windows, resetting them to default, which temporarily fixed the problem.

However, anytime I log out of my computer, or anytime it would go into the sleep mode, the settings are automatically reverted back. Is the problem stemming from Photoshop or Windows? Any help on this would be awesome.

Comment: This would be more of a tech support issue than one for graphic designers - however, Photoshop does not touch your computer's colour profile settings. It works alongside them, but is set separately.

Comment: Is it your computer or a work computer? Many users at my work have a similar problem that stems from the fact that central management resets their settings after they log out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, since I think we'd need access to your computer and the problematic image file to tell for sure what the problem is. Anyway, here goes . . .

The Windows Photo app doesn't support things like CMYK images or specialist colour profiles. I suspect this might be the problem. It probably has nothing to do with Photoshop or your computer's settings.

If you are designing for on-screen viewing, make sure the file you export from Photoshop is RGB (not CMYK) and that it's exported with an sRGB colour profile. This is the standard for colour reproduction on the web, and for displaying on computer screens/other devices.

Generally, you need specialist image editing software to view CMYK images properly in Windows. If the image is for use on the web, most browsers don't support CMYK files either, and even most consumer grade/home/orrice printers can't print CMYK files.